# How to get $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{n^2(1-\cos(x/n))}{1+x^6}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis

I try to compute limiting of the following integral
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{n^2(1-\cos(x/n))}{1+x^6}dx
$$

---

Note that for $x\ge 0$, we have $|1-\cos x|\le x^2/2$.

Then for $x\ge 0$,
$$
\frac{n^2(1-\cos(x/n))}{1+x^6}\le \frac{x^2}{2(1+x^6)}\in L^1((0,\infty))
$$

Hence,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{n^2(1-\cos(x/n))}{1+x^6}dx=2\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^\infty \frac{n^2(1-\cos(x/n))}{1+x^6}dx=2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{2(1+x^6)}dx=\frac{\pi}{6}
$$

Does my proof make sense?

Comment: its right to me, I can't see any error

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks! So that integral is also corrent?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't compute it value. But the inequality is correct, so you can apply the DCT